# Core-data concurrency and API Rest Service

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, afnetworking

I have some questions or clarifications about Coredata and API Rest interaction.

My Customer asks to use:

- Coredata to store some entities managed from iOS app;
- AFNetworking as networking library;

and also...

- I need to manage multithreading operation on entities;
- The app will go to 'off-line mode and the user can use it in this modality. When the app will be on-line I need to resynch the modified objects. For this I'm reading this tutorial:
  [How To Synchronize Core Data with a Web Service – Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1)

In particular I would to know if there are some best practises about the use of Coredata with concurrency. I have found some tutorials for concurrency with Coredata and I have seen that a possible approach for this is the use of a singleton. is this a good idea?

Can you also suggest me some good tutorial to use Coredata + AFNetworking?

Thanks

Comment: If you haven't done so already, I can highly recommend to read up on CoreData. There are a few books out there, but the one that finally made it all click for me is the one by Tim Roadley. Also the book by Marcus Zarra is often used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have requirements for CoreData and AFNetworking - you may want to look at using RestKit - which satisfies both requirements.

Regarding concurrency (which restkit uses internally) - you will need to implement a observer pattern to detect changes.  I'd suggest reading this blog article: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/core-data